# Listing all available default variants

Tags: plugin-craftcommerce

Folks:

I figured this would be simple but apparently not (for me, anyway).

- I have a product with two variants (orange and yellow).
- I have a page that lists all the available products.
- On that page, both variants appear. I really just need one and users
  can select their variant from a drop-down on the checkout page.

What I've got:

```
{# get the products from the categories #}
{% set products = craft.commerce.products.type('shirts,shorts') %}

{# show the product main image and link to the product page #}
<a href="{{ product.url }}">
    {% if product|length %}
        {% set asset = product.productHeroImage.first() %}
    <img src="{{ asset.url }}">{% endif %}
</a>
```

I did try `{% set products = craft.commerce.products.defaultVariant.type('shirts,shorts') %}` but get the same results.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, so this did have a really simple solution. Just use isDefault.

```
{% if variant.isDefault %}Show the product{% endif %}
```

Works like a charm.